What happens to quantum entanglement when one particle crosses the event horizon of a black hole?
I’m curious about the behavior of quantum entanglement in extreme scenarios. Specifically, what would happen if we sent one of a pair of entangled particles (say, a photon or electron) across the event horizon of a black hole, while the other particle remains on Earth?
1.  Would we still observe the expected quantum correlations when measuring the particle that remains on Earth?
2.  Could the event horizon of the black hole disrupt the quantum entanglement?
3.  How could we experimentally determine if the entanglement has been broken?

I understand that this involves both quantum mechanics and general relativity, making it a complex and possibly unresolved question. Are there any current theories or hypotheses that address this situation? Any insights or references to relevant research would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

What exactly does "observe the expected quantum correlations" mean, when you can never know the outcomes of observations on one of the particles?

Entanglement likely starts at 2 photon creation, one gets right and the other left. After there is no linkage. There are many hyped and misleading statements/papers about entangled pairs.

Also, objects can't cross event horizons. They can get infinitely close, but because time dilation is proportional to the distance from the event horizon (construct a Schwarzschild black hole and see), you can only approach it.

This question has been asked here before more than once and will end up being closed as a duplicate. And every time the logic in the question is flawed. As already mentioned in the comment above, nothing can cross the horizon for as long as the universe exists, meaning forever. A black hole is not an area of space behind the horizon, but a temporal tunnel to the infinite future (whatever this means).

Entanglement is a special form of the density operator of an ensemble. No information is "translated" between particles. Therefore, the event horizon will not affect measurements of observables. If two electrons are entangled such that one will yield spin "up" and the other spin "down" when measured, an observer inside the event horizon will measure "up" when the observer outside measures "down". Of course, there is no way for the observer inside to convey this information to the observer outside.

This answer is incorrect and follows the same logical flow as the question. When the observer inside receives the photon, its outside counterpart no longer exists.

@safesphere The ultimate fate of the outside counterpart photon has no effect on the eventual measurement of the photon inside. The inside photon doesn't "know" the outside photon no longer exists, and the density matrix probabilities must still be respected.

As I said above, this answer follows the same logical flow as the question. So what a surprise this answer is accepted. People here don’t want to lean, but to have their misconceptions confirmed by others with the same misconceptions. What a happy community

I think you're getting caught up in a figure of speech and missing the actual physics. Perhaps if I said "if" instead of "when" you would be able to understand better. Hopefully this clears up your misconception.

Your "constructive" criticism was whining about someone accepting an answer that you didn't like. The relative time difference between the two measurements is completely irrelevant. The second particle will eventually cross the event horizon, and by your own admission, the state of the second particle becomes defined, so the eventual measurement inside the event horizon will agree with the outside one. This agreement can't be communicated, as I said in my answer. I am happy to answer any questions you have on this topic, but further unprofessionalism will be disregarded.
